# Node can't find module that's in local dir

Tags: javascript, node.js, twilio

I have downloaded a twilio node module into a local directory where my project is.  But when I run the node file, it throws an error. Below the error here, I've outlined the directory.

The error:

```
gamacbook:twilioapp gattra$ node app.js

module.js:340
    throw err;
          ^
Error: Cannot find module 'node_modules/twilio/lib'
```

My local directory is:

```
twilioApp
    |_app.js
    |_index.html
    |_main.css
    |_script.js
    |_node_modules
        |_twilio
            |_lib
```

There are obviously a bunch of files in `twilio` directory but i'm trying to access those in `lib`.

My code is:

```
var accountSid = "removed";
var authToken = "removed";

var client = require('node_modules/twilio/lib')(accountSid, authToken);

app.get('/', function () { 
    client.messages.create({
        body: "Today is awesome and you rock!",
        to: phoneNumber,
        from: "removed"
    }, function (err, message) {
        process.stdout.write(message.sid);
    })
})
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's not how you should use modules in node. Simply:

```
var twilio = require('twilio')
```